# Grab link titles from site

Tags: php, html, web-scraping, domdocument

Hello it's possible to export to txt file from this site:

```
http://bitinfocharts.com/top-100-richest-bitcoin-addresses.html
```

all the addresses?

like:

```
1BPqtqBKoUjEq8STWmJxhPqtsf3BKp5UyE
1i7cZdoE9NcHSdAL5eGjmTJbBVqeQDwgw
etc...
```

I write this code:

```
<?
$html = file_get_contents('http://bitinfocharts.com/top-100-richest-bitcoin-addresses-5.html');
//Create a new DOM document
$dom = new DOMDocument;

//Parse the HTML. The @ is used to suppress any parsing errors
//that will be thrown if the $html string isn't valid XHTML.
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

//Get all links. You could also use any other tag name here,
//like 'img' or 'table', to extract other tags.
$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

//Iterate over the extracted links and display their URLs
foreach ($links as $link){
    //Extract and show the "href" attribute. 
    echo $link->getAttribute('href'), '<br>';
}
?>
```

but it print all the link titles, I need only the addresses...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done a lot simpler, just with text manipulation:

```
// get page
$html = file_get_contents('http://bitinfocharts.com/top-100-richest-bitcoin-addresses.html');
// split on bit just in front of address
$parts = explode('./bitcoin/address/',$html);
// dump the first part
array_shift($parts);
// get addresses from all subsequent parts
foreach ($parts as $part) $addresses[] = substr($part,0,strpos($part,'"'));
// show result
echo implode('<br>',$addresses);
```

The comments explain the code. I do admit however that working with the DOM has its elegance.

Comment: You're welcome, you too. But I think the solution of Ghost is very nice too, and to be honest, it's a better answer to your question. I gave it a ^.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is target each row, then target the anchor link. Example:

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://bitinfocharts.com/top-100-richest-bitcoin-addresses-5.html');
$dom = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($html);
libxml_clear_errors();
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$data = array();
$table_rows = $xpath->query('//h1[contains(text(), "Top 100 Richest Addresses Bitcoin")]/following-sibling::div[2]/table/tr');
foreach($table_rows as $row) {
    $cell = $xpath->query('./td[2]/a', $row);
    if($cell->length > 0) {
        $data[] = $cell->item(0)->nodeValue;

    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);

//file_put_contents('your_file.txt', implode("\n", $data));
```

`$data` looks like this: (some part of it)

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1KcRjW2roV8dtZoBMPD83nsFburPCY7RfR
    [1] => 1LovisaJ31py5rr37y5xpt3MzSjErpoeLr
    [2] => 1BE1ttHnrJ7YKkLgKpiNrp8uT3kM6Y1xfg
    [3] => 1Czx5RKaDkiE56RwdeLXRYL57ZxxdFxwhb
    [4] => 1BhQDdQgVyAekFZjT1nW8PB5XRt9VJhRs5
    [5] => 1JsSF3YLF4v9Fasfu6pqevwWc5Mtyf76M3
```